# Convert XML having multiple for-each case to CSV

Tags: java, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have written a Java Program that converts XML to CSV. But currently it is converting partial only.

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("src/main/resources/excel/Data.xml"), inputFile);
          File stylesheet = new File("src/main/resources/excel/Data.xsl");
          File xmlSource = new File("src/main/resources/excel/Data.xml");

          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

          StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
          Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);
          Source source = new DOMSource(document);
          String path = "src/main/resources/excel/validatedXmlToCSV.csv";
          Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File(path));
          transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
```

This is the Java code that takes XML and XSL and converts it to the CSV.

XML file that I am trying to convert it to CSV is:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <TECHNICIANID>AA5263</TECHNICIANID>
    <CUID>AA5263</CUID>
    <TURFS>
      <TURF>
        <AREANAME>CA_MILPITAS_ABEL_A</AREANAME>
        <DEFAULT>Y</DEFAULT>
        <ALTERNATE>Y</ALTERNATE>
      </TURF>
      <TURF>
        <AREANAME>CA_SNJS_WHITE_RD_A</AREANAME>
        <DEFAULT>Y</DEFAULT>
        <ALTERNATE>Y</ALTERNATE>
      </TURF>
    </TURFS>
  </row>
  <row>
    <TECHNICIANID>AC1964</TECHNICIANID>
    <CUID>AC1964</CUID>
    <TURFS>
      <TURF>
        <AREANAME>CA_MILPITAS_ABEL_A</AREANAME>
        <DEFAULT>Y</DEFAULT>
        <ALTERNATE>Y</ALTERNATE>
      </TURF>
      <TURF>
        <AREANAME>CA_SNJS_WHITE_RD_A</AREANAME>
        <DEFAULT>Y</DEFAULT>
        <ALTERNATE>Y</ALTERNATE>
      </TURF>
    </TURFS>
  </row>
</root>
```

Let me show you how I wrote XSL file that it not working properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >

<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/">TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE
<xsl:for-each select="/root/row">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(TECHNICIANID,',',CUID,'
&#xA;')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="/TURFS/TURF">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(AREANAME,',',DEAFAULT,',',ALTERNATE,',
&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently while converting it is printing row TECHNICIANID and CUID only. Other it is not printing.

Expected Output:

```
TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE
AA5263,AA5263,CA_MILPITAS_ABEL_A,Y,Y,CA_SNJS_WHITE_RD_A,Y,Y
AC1964,AC1964,CA_MILPITAS_ABEL_A,Y,Y,CA_SNJS_WHITE_RD_A,Y,Y
```

Comment: You have tagged this as `xslt-2.0` but your stylesheet declares `version="1.0"`. Are you sure you can use an XSLT 2.0 answer?

Comment: @michael.hor257k if that xslt works then I am good with it. I can give a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the inner `<xsl:for-each select="/TURFS/TURF">` should be `<xsl:for-each select="TURFS/TURF">`. And  `concat(AREANAME,',',DEAFAULT` should be `concat(AREANAME,',',DEFAULT`.

Comment: I made those changes, it is not printing.

Comment: @JeevanGyawali, it should output the values you previously did not select. There seem to some other inconsistencies between your wanted CSV result lines and your use of `&#xA;` in the XSLT so you probably need to output that line break after the inner `for-each` with e.g. `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` and remove the use of `&#xA;` in your concat calls e.g. use `<xsl:value-of select="concat(TECHNICIANID,',',CUID)"/>` but use a leading comma in e.g. `concat(',', AREANAME,',', DEFAULT,',',ALTERNATE)`.

Comment: it's working after removing &#xA from for-each

Comment: `<xsl:template match="/">TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE
<xsl:for-each select="/XBFTECH_T/XBFTECH_RECORD_UPD">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(TECHNICIANID,',',CUID,',')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="TURFS/TURF">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(AREANAME,',',DEFAULT,',',ALTERNATE,',')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(',',',
&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: How can I get header as fileType of XML? As you can see this header is hardcoded but I want to make it flexible, get it from XML itself: <xsl:template match="/">TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:value-of select=".//*[not(*)]" separator=","/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bF2MmXG/1

---

If you want to pick the values explicitly, then change:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//*[not(*)]" separator=","/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="TECHNICIANID, CUID, TURFS/TURF[1]/(AREANAME, DEFAULT, TALTERNATE), TURFS/TURF[2]/(AREANAME, DEFAULT, TALTERNATE)" separator=","/>
```

Comment: No, it is working. It is printing values in one row. Also if you pay attention then  there are places where I need to use multiple for-each

Comment: If you look at the linked demo, you will see that it returns exactly the result you have asked for.

Comment: How can I get header as fileType of XML? As you can see this header is hardcoded but I want to make it flexible, get it from XML itself: <xsl:template match="/">TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE

Comment: Please post a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: It is attached question so I thought it will be easier to follow up

Answer (score 0):

Your problem involves extracting data from a multilevel XML file and convert it to a CSV file. The Java code for this is complicated.

It is convenient to perform the conversion using SPL, the open-source Java package. You just need several lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =xml(file("Data.xml").read(),"root/row").conj(TECHNICIANID|CUID|TURFS.TURF.conj(~.array())) |
| 2 | =create(TECHNICIANID,CUID,TURFS/TURF/0/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/0/DEFAULT, TURFS/TURF/0/ALTERNATE,TURFS/TURF/1/AREANAME,TURFS/TURF/1/DEFAULT ,TURFS/TURF/1/ALTERNATE).record(A1) |
| 3 | =file("validatedXmlToCSV.csv").export@ct(A2) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as xml2csv.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st=con.prepareCall("call xml2csv()");
st.execute();
…
```